# Why only seven Immortals?

Tags: the-protector

When Kemal tells the story about the origins of the Protector, he implies that there have been seven immortals since the time that the Protector was made, hundreds of years previously. One of the other Immortals even says that "an ordinary mortal" has never joined them before. Not even Faysal did this for all the years that he was the only one and at a disadvantage. But why not?

We certainly know that they are capable of creating at least *one* additional Immortal, or with the strategem that they employed near the end of Season 3, multiple Immortals. It also seems that having more unkillable soldiers for their army would certainly increase their chances of success against the Protector. And, up to a point, as we've seen, they would be able to control the new Immortals, so they wouldn't need to fear a rebellion.

As such, why didn't the Immortals add to their numbers in the preceding centuries?

Answer (score -2):

According to ancient texts found in Qumran caves and fragments in historical records, ancient Nephilim, had children with human women, hybrids.
Hybrids were tall. All legends also mention a war between Nephilim and true gods, where the gods created flood to kill all nephilim.
Legend says, Noah was a hybrid, and hid 7 or 8 ancient Nephilim on his ark.
It is not clear but it seems there is 7 named ones and one that was not named, hid his name. Some guess he was Ahura Mazda, Iahveh, and all todays religions were made up to corrupt humans to follow this god and conquer the Earth. Which they did. Next what happened, he orderd burning all books under penalty of death to whole family.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What is your source for this?  Please make sure your answer is based on evidence provided by the show or its creators.

Comment: @DavidW - I know that it is hard to tell, but this has nothing to do with the show. It appears to be the respondent's theory about reality.

Comment: @Adamant I had a strong suspicion, but didn't want to make that assumption.